# -fno-unwind-tables and -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables does not work NDK clang++

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, clang++, compiler-flags

I'm compiling my C++ code using clang++ that comes with ndk21. I've set both compiler flags -fno-unwind-tables  and -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables but the number of entries in the unwind table do not reduce. I also checked by setting the opposite -funwind-tables  and -fasynchronous-unwind-tables but it doesn't increase either. setting -fno-exceptions does reduce the number of entries slightly which makes me think I'm passing the flags correctly. Does anyone have any idea why this could be the case?

My test program is very simple just 5 functions, all appending strings to strings. Is it that the minimum number of entries in the unwind table? I'm trying to reduce the binary size.

Comment: Are you including any static libraries? libc++_static.a, for example, will have it's own and your flags won't affect it.

Comment: @DanAlbert Yup that was it, absolutely right thank you, went down to from 52 to 1 and all three flags when I changed it from static linking with libc++ to shared. Clearly all of them were from the exceptions. Please make it the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the reason is that you're depending on some other libraries that *do* have unwind tables. The C++ stdlib is definitely built with them, so if you're using libc++_static.a they'll be added to your library. Since that code is already compiled, your compiler flags won't have any effect on it :)

I should also note that there are other reasons that you might want unwind tables even if you're not using exceptions. Crash handlers that you use might depend on them, for example.

Comment: Yup thank you, I was just mesing around with clang flags to see how low I can go before it breaks.