# Why doesn't -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables have any effect on a program with no exceptions, clang++?

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, clang++, compiler-flags

This is a followup question to [-fno-unwind-tables and -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables does not work NDK clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320330/fno-unwind-tables-and-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables-does-not-work-ndk-clang) but with a different piece of code and a different question. Building with Clang++ that comes with ndk 21 for Armeabi-v7a

I have a piece of code, in which I've removed all exception handling. Ran clang with `-fasynchronous-unwind-tables` and `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` and there was no difference to the unwind entries. Ran it with `-fno-unwind-tables` and it reduced by about 150 entries out of around 3000. I would think that all functions would have entries in the unwind tables and would correspond to asynchronous exceptions as clang wouldn't have found a single try/catch in my code so should have gotten removed with `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`. Why did `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` have no effect? I'm not statically linking.

Also, when I ran no-exceptions, there were 40 entries left behind. I have no clue what that is since I have dynamically linked everything. What else is in the unwind entries?

I don't think the original code should matter here beyond it has no exceptions. Hopefully the numbers alone should be enough to understand the problem.

Comment: My initial thought is "you may be linking to libraries that *may* throw exceptions that the compiler cannot know about and may need to handle". Using LTO might improve things for you.. just guessing here.

Comment: Well I'm dynamically linking my libraries so I'm not sure how the compiler would know. I'll still investigate a bit. But do you have any guesses as to why fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables does nothing, when basically my unwind table should pretty much be filled with asynchronous entries since i have no exceptions and compiler shouldn't think that anything thing might throw exceptions. Not even 1 seems odd.

Comment: did you ever find the answer? coincidentally I am playing with the same flags for the purpose of binary size reduction on Android, and seeing the same results - no effect on the size of the .eh_frame section with -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables